# VBA: a conexão subjacente estava fechada: erro inesperado em um recebimento

Tags: html, vba, selenium-webdriver

Eu tenho um projeto em VBA que faz interação com páginas web usando a referência SeleniumWrapper. No Windows vista business a aplicação funciona normalmente, porém, no Windows 7 aparece o erro relatado no titulo da pergunta

Segue o código:

```
    Sub x()
        Dim objCollection
        Dim objCollection1 As Object
        Dim numeroPregao, dataAssinatura, uasg, item, val, m
        Dim c As Integer
        Dim ULogin As Boolean, ieForm
        Dim MyPass As String, MyLogin As String
        Dim driver As New SeleniumWrapper.WebDriver


        driver.Start "chrome", "http://comprasnet.gov.br" 'inicia o navegador                              
        driver.Open "/acesso.asp?url=/Livre/Ata/ConsultaAta00.asp" 'navega até a pagina

        Set objCollection = driver.findElementByCssSelector("frame[name='main2']") 'o erro ocorre aqui
```

o erro é ejetado ultimo comando, porém a linha **driver.Open "/acesso.asp?url=/Livre/Ata/ConsultaAta00.asp" 'navega até a pagina**. não faz nada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

depois de muita pesquisa encontrei a solução!
O erro estava acontecendo pois o Chrome tinha atualizado para a versão mais recente e o ChromeDriver que eu estava utilizando não suportava esta versão do Chrome.
fiz o download da nova versão do ChromeDriver e colei dentro da pasta do Selenium e funcionou perfeitamente

versões do ChromeDriver para download: https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads